# Laravel Route resource não funciona

Tags: php, laravel, route

Tenho a seguinte rota que chama um formulário de edição no meu controller.

```
    <a href="{{ route('companies.edit', $companie->id) }}">{{$companie->id}}</a>
```

Route

```
    Route::resource('companies', 'CompaniesController');
```

Meu controller

```
    public function edit(Companie $companie)
    {
        $this->authorize('companies.edit');
    
        $accountings = Accounting::all();
        return view('admin.companies.edit', compact('companie', 'accountings'));
    }
```

O problema e que na minha view o retorno do meu 'companie' é nulo e deveria retornar a 'companie' que foi selecionada, e é possível ver que o parâmetro id esta sendo enviado pela url normalmente exemplo (/admin/companies/3/edit). Tentei de varias formas tentando pegar o id por $request->id porem sem sucesso.

Answer (score -3):

Você precisa declarar o $id nos parâmetros da função, e depois realizar a busca pela model.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $this->authorize('companies.edit');

    $companie = Companie::find($id);
    $accountings = Accounting::all();
    return view('admin.companies.edit', compact('companie', 'accountings'));
}
```